# Как написать такой запрос: "Итоговый запрос без условия с итоговыми данными типа "всего", "в том числе""

Tags: sql, aggregate

"Итоговый запрос без условия с итоговыми данными типа "всего", "в том числе""

Это часть курсовой.

Я спросил у преподавателя, что это значит, получил ответ "например, выбрать среднюю оценку студентов, и отдельно среднюю оценку с кафедры ПИ". Т.е. должны быть две колонки:

```
avg1  | avg2
------------
4.1   | 4.7
```

Окей, но как сделать это без условия? Для приведенного примера, у меня на уме только

```
select avg(mark) from student 
  join (select avg(mark) from student where cafedra='PI')
```

Но все равно тут есть условие. Как мне выполнить задание, не знаете?

Comment: Я не смог понять, что надо сделать. Добавьте пожалуйста пример входных данных. И скажите, какая у вас СУБД?

Comment: Из моего смутного понимания вашего вопроса. Возможно вам нужен `group by` ? Что-то в духе `select cafedra, avg(mark) from student group by cafedra`

Comment: *"например, выбрать среднюю оценку студентов, и отдельно среднюю оценку с кафедры ПИ"* `SELECT AVG(mark), AVG(CASE WHEN faculty='ПИ' THEN mark END) FROM table`

Comment: @viktorov, знаю, вопрос неясный, но точнее дать не могу.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо, надеюсь, это то, что имелось в виду.